# Debian Wheezy Networking Spontaneously Shuts Down

Tags: networking, debian

I have just recently upgraded to Wheezy. Since I have updated my server will spontaneously kill networking. What logs could I look in to see if I can find the issue? I have looked in /var/log and there are no logs that look relevant that have been updated in the past few days. This server runs headless so re-enabling networking means turning the server off and on again as I can't ssh to it.

Any suggestions would be welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var/log/syslog` should have something. You can run `dmesg` which may pick it up if it's a kernel module problem or something - to find the module name use `lspci -v | grep -i ethernet` and look for the module name a few lines later (it could be e1000 or something). Use the module name when grepping the dmesg output.

Comment: grepping dmesg output shows: eth1: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex, flow control both. It seems to shut down after about 2 days.

Comment: I'll think why that is. In the meantime, even if it is headless, why not install ssh (I thought it was already with Wheezy) and bring the eth0 device up with `ip link set eth0 up` or something, possibly followed by a`dhcpcd` call?